# Azure environment configurations screwing up AJAX calls? (Prismic, React, GraphQL, GatsbyJS)

Tags: azure, graphql

We currently have a project utilizing GatsbyJS/GraphQL to consume data from a Prismic headless CMS instance.

We have two environments:
 - A test 'static website' using an Azure Storage Account
 - A D1 Azure App Service

On the static site, our AJAX calls to the Prismic API work fine.  However, on our App Service, the AJAX calls spit out an error saying Uncaught (in promise) message: "Syntax Error: Unexpected Int "3657904102""

[GraphQL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwaIR.png)

Any thoughts on what environment configuration could be screwing up those calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

AJAX calls in Gatsby *only* ran when we changed the agent to a macOS machine.

No idea why, but currently neither Windows nor Linux agents work.  They will build and run fine, but AJAX calls throw an error.